# Not able to install VestiGO JPA Query Browser in Eclipse Helios

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse Helios for Java EE Apps.

I am facing problems while installing VESTIGO JPA Query Browser while installation. I am getting the error logs like this ...

```
 Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Vestigo Cumulus4j integration 1.0.1 (org.nightlabs.vestigo.cumulus4j.ui.feature.feature.group 1.0.1)
  Missing requirement: org.nightlabs.vestigo.ui 1.0.1 (org.nightlabs.vestigo.ui 1.0.1) requires 'package org.osgi.framework [1.7.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Vestigo Cumulus4j integration 1.0.1 (org.nightlabs.vestigo.cumulus4j.ui.feature.feature.group 1.0.1)
    To: org.nightlabs.vestigo.ui.feature.feature.group 1.0.1
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Vestigo - JDO JPA Query Browser 1.0.1 (org.nightlabs.vestigo.ui.feature.feature.group 1.0.1)
    To: org.nightlabs.vestigo.ui [1.0.1]
```

And here is the snap of the error ..

[image]

Can anyone tell me.. How can I fulfill  those required dependency for VESTIGO installation.

Comment: With some R&D, I cam to know that OSGI in eclipse is provided by EQUINOX. Now I want to update EQUINOX implementation but can not find a way to update it.

Answer (score 2):

From the error message of your installation, Vestigo UI requires 'org.osgi.framework' with version '1.7.0' as prerequisite.

I think the 'org.osgi.framework' has been updated to '1.7.0' in Eclipse Juno. You have to update your Helios to Juno firstly or directly download [Juno from eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) then install Vestigo upon it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kane. If this is only the solution then I will be using Android Developer Tool rather than Helios. Juno is the latest IDE and definitely it will work with Juno. But is there any way to upgrade   'org.osgi.framework' in Eclipse Helios ? OR How can I see the current version of  'org.osgi.framework'  in Eclipse Helios??

Comment: I think there is no way to only update Equinox without upgrading your Eclipse. The plug-in is required by your Eclipse package(AKA Eclipse java package, J2EE package and so on), you can't upgrade some of them separately. 'org.osgi.framework' is a package notion is OSGi, you can find its version in MANIFEST.MF of plug-in 'org.eclipse.osgi'.